# Networking Unity game over Internet with Node.js

Tags: node.js, networking, network-programming, unity-game-engine

I have a game I want to network over the internet, and wanted to confirm my understanding to make sure i'm not missing any technical or security issues that may arise if I go down this path.

I've managed to network my Unity Android Application on a local network using the built-in Unity networking tools, and I'd like to be able to 'match-make' the clients together over the internet. My plan is to host a node.js server on Digital Ocean as a point of contact for the clients. Clients will connect to the server, which will 'pair up' clients by exchanging IP addresses, to form a direct connection between them, and then function the same as if they were on a local network. I like this method as it is low overhead on the server end, with its only role being as a point of contact for the clients, pairing them up, then  disconnecting and waiting for more requests, which node seems particularly suited to.

I do not plan to store any data on the server, or perform any strenuous processing, other than possibly matchmaking players of similar skill level.

Does this sound achievable?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks good to me.

Comment: Will there be any sort of firewall/port forwarding issues if I connect clients directly?

Comment: I don't know enough Unity, nor your application to predict this point. Hope you will get a more complete answer soon !

Comment: Thanks for the help. There doesn't seem to be a lot of overlap between Unity developers and networking programmers from what I've seen, making it difficult to find answers to questions like these.

Answer (score 0):

Use photon unity networking its easier and you dont have to worry about hosting.

Comment: I don't know if Photon is suitable. Their pricing can get quite steep and it seems more targeted towards applications that need a dedicated server for a game session. I already own a droplet with Digital Ocean so attaching a node server to it is no additional cost.